# I want to read \t\t at the end of InputStream in Java

Tags: java, string, sockets, parsing

I have the following code

```
InputStream inputStream = sock.getInputStream();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

String line = null;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] data = line.split("\\s+");

//rest of the code
```

The sender is supposed to send the following String

```
String DataToSend = "Name John City NewYork \t\t"
```

What I want is confirm the message coming from client to server ends with double tab \t\t, it doesn't show in the String[] data.

Comment: What's the problem with the code?

Comment: Nothing is wrong!! I juts do not know how to do it? how to confirm the inputstream ends with \t\t

Comment: `if (line.endsWith("\t\t"))` before `String[] data = line.split("\\s+");`

Comment: So you want to read the entire stream, then at the end check that the last two bytes read are `\t\t`?

Comment: (line.endsWith("\t\t")) did work, but didn't work with "\n\n"

Comment: Yeah exactly I want to read the last two bytes

Comment: line.split("\\s+"); this statement considers \t\t as space character, and erases them from result string array

Comment: When I read line with out split it doesn't have \t I have tried also \r \n, it didn't have any

Comment: Then it stands to reason that the stream does not contain `\t\t` at the end. If you are convinced it does, then just use `String.replace` to replace `\t\t` with something else, and see if what you replaced it with shows up. `BufferedReader.readLine` does not split on tabs, so if it is there, you should be able to get something from carrying out that test

Comment: exactly but why is that? I'm trying to mark the end of a socket's client's message by double tabs or double newline

Comment: You need to consider what `readLine()` actually does ... with newlines.

Comment: And you need to make your question a lot more clear.  Put all of the extra detail into the question itself ... in a coherent fashion ... so that someone reading the question can understand the *complete* problem you are asking us to help you solve.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to understand these 2 things:

1. `reader.readLine()` will give you string without the newline,
   because it reads until newline.
2. `line.split("\\s+")` will give you string(s) without whitespace characters, because it splits based on the whitespace characters.
   `\t`, `\n`, `\r`, `space`, are all whitespace characters.

Now, depends on what you want, there are few things that you can do:

1. check `\t\t` at the end of each line
   You can check before splitting the strings, sample code:

```
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream("hello\t\t".getBytes());
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.endsWith("\t\t")) { // check if it ends with \t\t
        // do something
    }
    String[] data = line.split("\\s+");
}
```

Note: when the `\t\t` is in the middle of the string e.g. `hello\t\tworld`, it will not be handled.

2. read strings until `\t\t`
   You can use `Scanner` and set `\t\t` as the delimiter, sample code:

```
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream("hello\t\tworld\nit's me".getBytes());

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream);
scanner.useDelimiter("\t\t");

int count = 1;
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String data = scanner.next();
    System.out.println("data number " + count + ":");
    System.out.println(data);
    System.out.println();
    count++;
}
```

Output:

```
data number 1:
hello

data number 2:
world
it's me
```

Comment: It reads until line terminator or end of stream, and throws away the terminator.